# gfortran error while installing using homebrew

Tags: homebrew, gfortran

Any help with this problem which I faced while trying gfortran using homebrew. Thank you very much in advance.

```
    bash-3.2$ brew install gfortran
    Warning: gfortran-4.8.0 already installed, it's just not linked
    bash-3.2$ brew link gfortran
    Linking /usr/local/Cellar/gfortran/4.8.0... Warning: Could not link gfortran. Unlinking...

    Error: Could not symlink file: /usr/local/Cellar/gfortran/4.8.0/share/gcc-4.8.0/python
    /libstdcxx/v6/printers.py
    Target /usr/local/share/gcc-4.8.0/python/libstdcxx/v6/printers.py already exists. 
    You may need to  delete it.
    To force the link and delete this file, do:
    brew link --overwrite formula_name

    To list all files that would be deleted:
    brew link --overwrite --dry-run formula_name
    bash-3.2$
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This looks like another GCC 4.8 installation, either from Homebrew or elsewhere, is conflicting with the gfortran install. GFortran is based on GCC so they can collide.

The `gcc48` Homebrew formula looks like it has an undocumented conflict with `gfortran`. Both want to symlink /usr/local/share/gcc-4.8.0. I was able to reproduce your error with `brew tap homebrew/versions; brew install gcc48; brew install gfortran`

Head on over to the [Homebrew issue tracker on GitHub](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/issues) and report this conflict as a bug.

As a workaround, if you don't need that GCC 4.8.0, either `brew unlink gcc48` (if it's from homebrew) or uninstall it, and then try the gfortran install again.

UPDATE: Looks like the Homebrew folks are already aware of this issue. There is a fix for it included in [this pull request (#19382)](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/pull/19382).